# Powershell attributes?

Tags: powershell, metadata

is it possible to assign some metadata Attributes to powershell macros? I have the set of macros and I want to encapsulate them to logical groups. I imagine something like:

```
[UnitTest]
function Do-Something()
{
...
}
```

and then pass all loaded macros in runtime and filter them out like:

```
$macrosInRuntime = Get-Item function: 
$unitTestMacros = $macrosInRuntime | 
    ? {$_.Attributes -contain "UnitTest"} # <-- ???
foreach ($macro in $unitTestMacros)
{
   ....
}
```

I will be greatful for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting question... There are no such attributes of functions, AFAIK. But I think there is a half-hacky way that uses comment-based help attributes (perhaps not even hacky at all but I am not quite sure).

```
<#
.FUNCTIONALITY
    TEST1
#>
function Do-Something1
{}

<#
.FUNCTIONALITY
    TEST2
#>
function Do-Something2
{}

Get-ChildItem Function: | %{
    $fun = $_.Name
    try {
        Get-Help $fun -Functionality TEST* | %{
            switch($_.Functionality) {
                'TEST1' { "$fun is for test 1" }
                'TEST2' { "$fun is for test 2" }
            }
        }
    }
    catch {}
}
```

Output:

```
Do-Something1 is for test 1
Do-Something2 is for test 2
```

Perhaps this approach might be useful in some scenarios.

See also the section COMMENT-BASED HELP KEYWORDS in help:

```
man about_Comment_Based_Help
```

---

**UPDATE**
Though the answer above is accepted, I am still not quite happy with it. Here is yet another approach that is definitely not hacky. It also has an advantage, see the comments. This approach uses extra aliases with conventional names.

```
# Functions to be used in tests, with any names
function Do-Something1 { "Something1..." }
function Do-Something2 { "Something2..." }

# Aliases that define tests, conventional names are UnitTest-*.
# Note: one advantage is that an alias can be defined anywhere,
# right where a function is defined or somewhere else. The latter
# is suitable in scenarios when we cannot modify the source files
# (or just do not want to).
Set-Alias UnitTest-Do-Something1 Do-Something1
Set-Alias UnitTest-Do-Something2 Do-Something2

# Get UnitTest-* aliases and extract function names for tests.
Get-Alias UnitTest-* | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Definition

# Or we can just invoke aliases themselves.
Get-Alias UnitTest-* | % { & $_}
```

Answer (score 2):

Organizing and grouping commands is an ongoing dilemma in PowerShell. It is something that will always have to be managed. However, there are some best practices around naming cmdlets and functions that can work if you are diligent. You probably have noticed that all cmdlets are in the verb-noun format. IE `Get-Process`, `Set-Item`, etc. What a lot of people do is add a third part to the command which groups the nouns together. For example, in the world of Active Directory, you don't have `get-user`, but rather `get-aduser`.

One thing you could do, and it may not be the prettiest thing, is to name your unit test functions with some 2 or 3 letter sequence of your choosing. Let's say you chose something incredibly original like UT for unit test. Your function would then be

```
function Do-UTSomething { "Something was done" }
```

Once you have all your UT functions, you can use the Get-Command cmdlet to iterate through them like so

```
Get-Command *UT* -commandtype function
```

Also, if you go a bit further and package them into a module, you could do one better and sort by that module.

```
Get-Command -module MyUnitTest
```

You can get all kinds of information on modules by using

```
help about_modules
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but this was not my point. I have already name convetions and macro set created where there is no way to rename them (because there is a lot of other dependent macros which are using them)